# loopback-connector-postgresql: jsonpath in the "where" condition

Tags: loopback, loopback4

The model is stored in postgresql. Something like:

```
{
    id: <serial>
    data: <json> {
        someIds: [<int>, ...]
    }
}
```

How to add a rule `jsonb_path_match(data::jsonb, 'exists($.someIds[*] ? (@ == 3))')` to the filter (where)? 
In this case, the value '3' `'(@ == 3)'` shall be determined by the user.

Answer (score 0):

[loopback-connector-postgresql](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-postgresql) does not support JSON/JSONB datatype yet. There is a pull request opened to contribute such feature, but it was never finished by the author - see [#401](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-postgresql/pull/401).

As a workaround, you can execute a custom SQL query to perform `jsonb_patch_match`-based search of your data.

Instructions for LoopBack 3: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Executing-native-SQL.html

```
dataSource.connector.execute(sql_stmt, params, callback);
```

Instructions for LoopBack 4: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.repository.defaultcrudrepository.execute.html

```
const result = await modelRepository.execute(sql_stmt, params, options);
```